# c++ type inference recursive functions

Tags: c++, auto

Trying to understand why the type deduction is failing here with conditional operator.
Something in the standard trying to prevent type deduction in this case? Any pointers to understand this would be great.

```
auto mfact(int i)
{
    return (0==i) ? 1 : i * mfact(i-1);
}

auto mfact2(int i)
{
    if (0 == i)
        return 1;

    else
        return i * mfact2(i-1);
}
```

> ```
> error: use of ‘auto mfact(int)’ before deduction of ‘auto’    
>     return (0==i) ? 1 : i * mfact(i-1);
> ```

Comment: You should *at least* post your compiler error message. At *best* post a [mcve].

Comment: The return type is deduced once all code in the function has been examined. Therefore using the function signature in the function's code is premature. You'll have to state the return type in the declaration.

Comment: @RichardHodges the `mfact2` fails to compile if you swap conditions, placing `return i * mfact2(i-1);` above the `return 1;`. Does it mean that type is being deduced by the first return statement compiler finds? Tested with GCC 7.1.1

Comment: @SergeyB. hmm good question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in `mfact` is the ternary operator. The semantics of that operator specify that the type of the expression is the common type of the two conditional sub-expressions (I'm paraphrasing a bit).

What is the common type? Why it's `int` and... A type left to be deduced.
Ah, no problem! What's the type to be deduced? It's the type of the ternary operator...

We have a chicken and egg problem. The entire function definition is ill-formed because the type of the expression cannot be determined.

What about `mfact2`? It has two separate return statements. The first one being of a plain integer. Since a function can only have a single return type, return type deduction requires the two return return statements not to conflict.

To quote the C++14 standard revision:

[[dcl.spec.auto/2]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.spec.auto#2)

> The placeholder type can appear with a function declarator in the
>   decl-specifier-seq, type-specifier-seq, conversion-function-id, or
>   trailing-return-type, in any context where such a declarator is valid.
>   If the function declarator includes a trailing-return-type
>   ([dcl.fct]), that specifies the declared return type of the function.
>   *If the declared return type of the function contains a placeholder
>   type, the return type of the function is deduced from return
>   statements in the body of the function, **if any.***

So one return statement to deduce the type is enough, and:

[[dcl.spec.auto/9]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.spec.auto#9)

> If a function with a declared return type that contains a placeholder
>   type has multiple return statements, the return type is deduced for
>   each return statement. If the type deduced is not the same in each
>   deduction, the program is ill-formed.

In this simple case, the first statement requires it to be `int`, and the second contains a recursive call. Since the same function overload can have only a single return type, the recursive call must be of type `int` as well. The two return statements agree.